# Twisted receiving data within dataReceived()

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to write a server using Twisted framework and would like to receive the data multiple times

```
class Echo(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print " got connection from : " + str(self.transport.getPeer())

    def dataReceived(self, data):

        '''
        get the client ip
        '''
        if(len(data)>40):
            '''
            initial setup message from the client
            '''
            client_details = str(self.transport.getPeer())#stores the client IP as a string
            i = client_details.find('\'')#process the string to find the ip
            client_details = client_details[i+1:]
            j = client_details.find('\'')
            client_ip = client_details[:j]


            '''
            Extract the port information from the obtained text
            ''' 
            data = data.split('@')
            port1 = data[0]
            port2 = data[1]
            port3 = data[2]

       if int(data) == 1:
           method1(client_ip,port1)

       if int(data) == 2:
           method2(client_ip,port2)
```

My question: The method1 and method2 are called only if it receives a message from the client with appropriate integer data in it. Is there a way in which I can wait on client for receiving the data inside the dataReceived() method or should I just do it sequentially in the dataReceived() method itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dataReceived` method is invoked when some data is received.  In order to wait for more data to be received, you just have to return from `dataReceived` so that it can be called again.

Also, TCP is not message-based, it is stream-based.  Your `dataReceived` method cannot count upon always receiving a complete message, so your example code is incorrect.  [See this frequently asked question](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith) on the Twisted Matrix Labs website for more information.

Comment: so would the order of the data be preserved and the variables would be set in order to use for further incoming messages? 
I haven't tried it out that way but I will test it out now.

Comment: technically, the "variables" (things set like `x = 1`) won't be; "attributes" (things set like `self.x = 1`) will.  This is a basic Python issue though, nothing to do with Twisted.

Comment: When you say that `dataReceived cannot count upon always receiving a complete message`, it raises another doubt, if have multiple clients connecting at the same time, will the messages sent by clients be treated as a single stream or will those be different?

Comment: If you have multiple clients connected, `buildProtocol` will be called on your factory to create a new `Echo` instance for each connection.  That instance will receive only the messages for that client.